# How does Gandalf get his staff back in The Hobbit: The Battle Of The Five Armies?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, gandalf, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In The Hobbit: The Battle Of The Five Armies, Gandalf's staff was broken when he was captured, but after his rescue he somehow got his staff back. How did this happen?

Comment: Gandalf's staff was destroyed when he [fought Sauron in DoS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7_U6y8kJaY) and replaced in BotFA by Radagast in a deleted scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40oFmq1k8SE is that what you mean?

Comment: @Richard Yes it is.

Comment: I'm confused. If that's what you're referring to, why have you accepted an answer that talks about the staff in the next film?

Comment: It might not be the exact answer that I expected but still with your first comment I get the answer.

Comment: He went to Jamaica, had a romantic adventure...that's how Gandalf got his grooves back.

Comment: @Paul I didn't get the reference.

Comment: @onurcanbektas. Sorry, there was a romantic comedy movie a while back called How Stella Got Her Groove Back which has the plot I referred to.

Comment: @Paul Oh, I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gandalf's own (original) staff was indeed destroyed when he fought against Sauron at the end of 'The Desolation of Smaug'. As you can see from the footage, it quite literally turned into dust and blew away.

As you can see from this (deleted) scene from the Extended Edition of 'The Battle of the Five Armies', his own staff was then replaced by Radagast the Brown's

> "Take this. If what you say is true, then you'll need it more than I"

Comment: Thank you, you answer is much clearer. The other one had me so confused. :) +1

Comment: @RedCaio - I was thoroughly convinced by OPs actions until I realised what he was after.

Answer (score 4):

### The staff was damaged, but not destroyed.

> Gandalf, to date is seen with five different variations of his staff,
>   three of those as the Grey wizard. 
>   . . . 
>   After his staff is destroyed by Sauron, he then acquires the staff of Radagast the Brown which he uses
>   in the Battle of the Five Armies. Whilst attempting to use the staff
>   against a troll Gandalf runs into complications when the crystal
>   inserted in the top of the staff fails to respond to his magical
>   incantation. Gandalf then dodges the troll's attacks and attempts a
>   strike with the staff, which also fails to have any effect. Gandalf,
>   eventually, harnesses the power of the staff without the crystal as he
>   is seen to attack Saruman in the Wizard's Duel at Orthanc. Later on,
>   the staff is damaged in the Battle of the Five Armies, and the root
>   like structure on the crown of the staff is completely withered away,
>   leaving Gandalf with the staff seen in The Fellowship of the Ring.
>    - The dubious [LOTR wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard_Staff)

The wiki, while a poorly sourced information font, is supported by visual comparison of the staff.

[image: GandalfStaff]
<sub>(source: [thelandofshadow.com](http://www.thelandofshadow.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/RadagastStaffGandalf2.jpg))</sub>

That is, indeed, same the badly-beaten staff of Radagast the Brown.

[image: GandalfLOTR]